# Why does the "Thug Life" sign change in "Ralph Breaks the Internet"?

Tags: ralph-breaks-the-internet

I was watching [this trailer + scene compilation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fO49iABgaCQ) of *Ralph Breaks the Internet*, and while going frame by frame as they're entering the internet (0:09 in the video), I noticed something odd.

There's a building/site that has a picture of a cat and the words "Thug Life" that they zoom past:

[image: thug life]

But, for the last two frames, it changes to something different.

[image: voln]

What is this?

**What is this sign supposed to be, and why did it change in the middle?**

Comment: It's Yelp not voln https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_large_assets/19f90cad684f/assets/img/brand_guidelines/Yelp_RGB_fullcolor_outline.png

Comment: It's a digital billboard I assume...think Times Square / Piccadilly Circus

Comment: https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/10f465728d775b2b46ab9dd285757431

Comment: try using any meme page (thug life with cat) without adblocker. this is exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

As [Paulie_D](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95758/why-does-the-thug-life-sign-change-in-ralph-breaks-the-internet#comment161881_95758) suggested it's just like a digital changing sign with not much depth.

Thug life cat is popular meme and the other sign you identified as voln belong to [Yelp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yelp) which is one of the famous crowd-sourced company.